# why "text-overflow: ellipsis" property of div not working for its child div

Tags: html, css

CSS property `text-overflow: ellipsis` is not working on child div which has class name `cluster-name`.

```css
.ft-column {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 4px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ft-column>.cluster-name {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="ft-column">
  <div>Cluster</div>
  <div class="pull-left cluster-name">FQDN</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it should be working, can you create a snippet / fiddle?

Comment: It is working. You need give the child div a small width and more content in it to see.

Answer (score 1):

You should give the parent div `width` so that when the **child overflows the width it will trigger the style**.This will also work if you give width to the child div but it will hard to manage as the parent is the wrapper so it's better **to manage the parent div.**

```css
.ft-column {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 4px; 
  width: 20%;
}

.cluster-name{
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="ft-column">
  <div>Cluster</div>
  <div class="pull-left cluster-name">FQDNsaxaxasxsaxsaxasxvfdvdvfvdfvfd</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.ft-column 
{
 flex-basis: 0;
 flex-grow: 1;
 padding: 4px; 
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 overflow: hidden
 }
 div.cluster-name {
  white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 2em; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
   
      
  }
```

```html
<div class="ft-column">
    <div>Cluster</div>
    <div class="pull-left cluster-name">FQDN</div>
</div>
```

Define `width`for `.cluster-name`then run the code `text-overflow: ellipsis;` are worked try it now

Answer (score 0):

Please rearrange your CSS as follows, here am adding width to the child.

```css
.ft-column {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 4px; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden
}
.ft-column > .cluster-name {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ft-column">
    <div>Cluster</div>
    <div class="pull-left cluster-name">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please go through it, https://jsfiddle.net/ManiAnand/5v6pfy9w/